# Why can't I use this geojson stored on my s3 bucket with amcharts?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, geojson, amcharts, amcharts4

I want to create a clickable map similar to one given [here](https://geology.com/world/world-map.shtml). If you click on the link it takes you to another page. I want to do a similar thing but with a geojson file I have for Italy. So following on from a previous [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371767/how-do-i-create-a-clickable-map-where-clicking-on-a-specific-part-of-the-map-tak) I made, I decided to use amcharts. Since I am new to javascript and html I decided to first play around with some relevant examples by just using my own GeoJSON file. Here is the code I am trying to use

```
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<script>
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
chart.geodataSource.url = "https://walruswondersitaly.s3.amazonaws.com/Regions.json"
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
});
var label = chart.chartContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
</script>
```

The above code is adapted from an example given in the [documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/)

But when I tested it on codeopen and tried it in Wix it just says 'Unable to load file'. As you can see the GeoJSON file is stored as an object in amazon s3. I made sure the bucket was set to 'block all public access off' and read access was given to the public when I originally uploaded it to the bucket. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: is your s3bucket public and have appropriate cors policies attached?

Comment: Because it is wrongly structurated if it is a geoJson it is missing the ID wich has to be unique.

Comment: @DanielA.White When I created the s3 bucket I unchecked 'Block all public access'. Is this what you meant?

Comment: you also have to enable cors: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

Comment: @Carlos1232 But that geoJson file is created from a shape file which I converted to geoJson using QGIS. I can open the resulting geoJSON file after it was created using QGIS so it must have saved it properly?

Comment: @DanielA.White I am just reading through the documentation. I tried to copy and paste some of the code here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-corsand also adding a GET and using https://codepen.io instead of http://www.example1.com but it still isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another source and It worked. Its weird I think that your GeoJSON is malformed or something.

```js
var chart2 = am4core.create("chartdiv2", am4maps.MapChart);
chart2.geodataSource.url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/elboman/5ee92356f49875da7337/raw/7008305a4b065a76a2c5103cd7698d990c98661a/italian-regions.geojson';
chart2.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
var polygonSeries = chart2.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  chart2.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
});
var label2 = chart2.chartContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
label2.text = "Italy";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv, #chartdiv2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

With your `JSON` + `id`

```js
var chart2 = am4core.create("chartdiv2", am4maps.MapChart);
chart2.geodataSource.url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Carlos123211/PeruGeoJson/master/italy.json';
chart2.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
var polygonSeries = chart2.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  chart2.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
});
var label2 = chart2.chartContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
label2.text = "Italy";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that definitely works, but that GeoJSON doesn't seem to have the same detail I need. Anyways the GeoJSON opens absolutely fine with QGIS which is a very popular open source spatial software program so I assume there is nothing wrong with the GeoJSON file itself. If you would like you can look at that GeoJSON file yourself to check. The link is given in the code in my question (it's on public).

Comment: Do you think it could be a permissions problem like @DanielA.White suggested?

Comment: Seems like that's the problem(CORS problem). Also you json is too large, just for adding those details try to look for another if posible; I also added a gitrepo with the correct JSON(missin the id's).

Comment: actually I've managed to find a tool that makes a much smaller version of the one in that s3 bucket. Could you link me to your repo that you created? Otherwise I can just use the one that you used in your answer.

Comment: This is the repo [italy.json](https://github.com/Carlos123211/PeruGeoJson/blob/master/italy.json)

Comment: Thanks. Accepting your answer now as it probably work. If I do something similar and make my JSON smaller and put it in a public repo from my own github account like you have it should still work? Is there anything else I would need to do?

Comment: Yes it would work, but remeber that you have to have ID inside properties.